# Count object in array (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to count the objects in an array, I have this code which does not work in HTML.
It has to be shown in HTML.

I only want it to show one of the object at time:
Type:
Chocolate: 1, Fruit: 2, Food: 3, Liquid: 2

```js
//This is the variable, i need to count
var markers = [{
    type: "Chocolate",
    name: "KitKat",
    group: "candy",
    icon: "candy",
    coords: [5246, 8980],
  },
  {
    type: "Fruit",
    name: "Orange",
    group: "fruits",
    icon: "fruis",
    coords: [9012, 5493],
  },
  {
    type: "Fruit",
    name: "Banana",
    group: "fruits",
    icon: "fruis",
    coords: [9012, 5493],
  },
  {
    type: "Food",
    name: "Rice",
    group: "foods",
    icon: "foods",
    coords: [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    type: "Food",
    name: "Meat",
    group: "foods",
    icon: "foods",
    coords: [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    type: "Food",
    name: "Beam",
    group: "foods",
    icon: "foods",
    coords: [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    type: "Liquid",
    name: "Water",
    group: "liquids",
    icon: "liquids",
    coords: [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    type: "Liquid",
    name: "Coffe",
    group: "liquids",
    icon: "liquids",
    coords: [6724, 9556],
  },
]

var count = []

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  count[markers[i].type] = count[markers[i].type] + 1 || 1;
}
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = count;
```

```html
<div id='data'></div>
```

It has to look like this

```
    Chocolate: 1, Fruit: 2, Food: 3, Liquid: 2
```

I hope somebody can help me, it has to be vanilla javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` too to count fruit types.

```js
var markers = [
    {
      type:"Chocolate",
      name:"KitKat",
      group:"candy",
      icon:"candy",
      coords:[5246,8980],
    },
    {
      type:"Fruit",
      name:"Orange",
      group:"fruits",
      icon:"fruis",
      coords:[9012,5493],
    },
    {
      type:"Fruit",
      name:"Banana",
      group:"fruits",
      icon:"fruis",
      coords:[9012,5493],
    },
    {
      type:"Food",
      name:"Rice",
      group:"foods",
      icon:"foods",
      coords:[6724,9556],
    },
    {
      type:"Food",
      name:"Meat",
      group:"foods",
      icon:"foods",
      coords:[6724,9556],
    },
    {
      type:"Food",
      name:"Beam",
      group:"foods",
      icon:"foods",
      coords:[6724,9556],
    },
    {
      type:"Liquid",
      name:"Water",
      group:"liquids",
      icon:"liquids",
      coords:[6724,9556],
    },
    {
      type:"Liquid",
      name:"Coffe",
      group:"liquids",
      icon:"liquids",
      coords:[6724,9556],
    },
 ];


const countFruitTypes = markers.reduce((a, {type}) => {
    a[type] = (a[type] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(countFruitTypes);
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and for further reading, this question has some good explanations on how reduce works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934992/main-difference-between-map-and-reduce

Answer (score 1):

1) You'll have to make `count` an Object. It'll allow you to store count of different type unlike array.

2) You can't show `Object` directly onto the HTML page. You'll have to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it.

```js
var markers = [
  {
    type:"Chocolate",
    name:"KitKat",
    group:"candy",
    icon:"candy",
    coords:[5246,8980],
  },
  {
    type:"Fruit",
    name:"Orange",
    group:"fruits",
    icon:"fruis",
    coords:[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    type:"Fruit",
    name:"Banana",
    group:"fruits",
    icon:"fruis",
    coords:[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Rice",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Meat",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Beam",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Liquid",
    name:"Water",
    group:"liquids",
    icon:"liquids",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Liquid",
    name:"Coffe",
    group:"liquids",
    icon:"liquids",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
];

var count = {}

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  count[markers[i].type] = count[markers[i].type] + 1 || 1 ;
}
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(count);
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

---

**Alternate solution** without using `JSON.stringify` and using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Also for your reference since you're new to coding, I have used [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to combine the `key` and `value` into a string.

```js
var markers = [
  {
    type:"Chocolate",
    name:"KitKat",
    group:"candy",
    icon:"candy",
    coords:[5246,8980],
  },
  {
    type:"Fruit",
    name:"Orange",
    group:"fruits",
    icon:"fruis",
    coords:[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    type:"Fruit",
    name:"Banana",
    group:"fruits",
    icon:"fruis",
    coords:[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Rice",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Meat",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Beam",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Liquid",
    name:"Water",
    group:"liquids",
    icon:"liquids",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Liquid",
    name:"Coffe",
    group:"liquids",
    icon:"liquids",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
];

var count = {}

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  count[markers[i].type] = count[markers[i].type] + 1 || 1 ;
}

var countString = '';

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(count)) {
  countString += `${key}: ${value} `;
}

document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = countString;
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything else I can use JSON.stringify? because it is a report and we have not learned about JSON.stringify - what about "toString() Method"?

Comment: No `toString()` won't work on `Object`. Alternatively, you can loop over the `object` using [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and construct a string.

Comment: Sorry, how could i do that?  thanks again for helping me, i am new to coding

Comment: @CodingWomen updated the answer with the alternate approach.