# How to filter an array of objects only by name property? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects called movies and I would like to create a new array only with the name property, I've used the forEach method but I need to do it with the filter method:

Expected output with filter method:

**[ 'Jumanji', 'Harry P', 'Toy Story' ]**

```
let movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry P',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

let movies_names = [];
movies.forEach(movie => {
    movies_names.push(movie.name);
});

console.log('movies_names', movies_names)
```

With filter method I'm able to see the names but when I return them I see the original array.

```js
let movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry P',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

let newAr = movies.filter((item, index, arr) => {
  console.log('item', item.name)
  return item.name
  // console.log('index', index)
  // console.log('arr', arr.name)
})


console.log('newAr', newAr)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the filter condition?

Comment: Only filter by name @BerkKurkcuoglu

Comment: Filter is for filtering certain elements from the array depending on a condition and you should return a boolean value from the predicate, in this case all names are truthy so you get back the original array. What you are actually looking for is the map function.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `.filter()` - _"The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function."_ - is the right tool?

Comment: @Andres You didn't understand Berk's question, filtering is done by using a condition, like Andreas said, you're probably not filtering the array at all.

Comment: With the expected output this is a perfect dupe of: [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) - But why do you ask for `.filter()`? o.O

Comment: @Andreas I thought there was a way with filter function to only filter by name

Comment: That's not filtering, thats mapping,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.filter` will filter the array removing unwanted items, You're looking for [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to keep the same array length changing the value of each element of the array :

```js
let movies = [{
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry P',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

let newAr = movies.map((item, index, arr) => {
  return item.name
})


console.log('newAr', newAr)
```

Comment: Thanks @Taki but is there a way to do it with filter method?

Comment: @Andres , i edited the answer, `Array.filter` removes unwanted items, it's not doing what you're expecting

Comment: Why didn't you vote to close as dupe of: [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to use is `map` but `reduce` would also do the job. To know more about which one to use when [checkout this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934992/main-difference-between-map-and-reduce)

```js
let movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry P',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

const newMoviesArrUsingMap = movies.map(cur => cur.name);
const newMoviesArrUsingReduce = movies.reduce((acc,cur) => [...acc, cur.name], []);

console.log(newMoviesArrUsingMap);
console.log(newMoviesArrUsingReduce);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry P',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];
movies_names = movies.map(movie=>movie.name)
console.log(movies_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

This prblem fit with map method: [Map W3Schools doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

```js
let movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry P',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

let newAr = movies.map(item => item.name)

console.log(newAr)
```