# javascript: create dictionary from array of key-values objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of objects.

```
const ar = [ {0 : "A"}, {1 : "B"}];
```

I want to create an dictionary from it

```
const di =  {0 : "A", 1 : "B"};
```

I am a little struggling with this conversion. How it is possible to do it using map or reduce?

```
const di = ar.map( ob => (???) }
```

Comment: `const di = Object.assign({}, ...arr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can be used to merge all objects. Be aware that the keys need to be unique otherwise you will overwrite them.

The merging is done with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const ar = [{0 : "A"}, {1 : "B"}];

const di = ar.reduce((acc, obj) => ({...acc, ...obj}));

console.log(di);
```

Another simple approach is the use of [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const ar = [{0 : "A"}, {1 : "B"}];

const di = Object.assign({}, ...ar);

console.log(di);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here instead of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will give you an array of objects but what you need is an object will all keys. So [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the best tool for it.

[Main difference between map and reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934992/main-difference-between-map-and-reduce)

```js
const ar = [{ 0: "A" }, { 1: "B" }];
const di = { 0: "A", 1: "B" };

const result = ar.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  Object.keys(curr).forEach((k) => (acc[k] = curr[k]));
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```