# Replace filter and map with reduce

Tags: javascript

I want to replace this filter and map using, with reduce:

```
      simpleFilter: fields
        .filter((f) => {
          const type = getUnifiedDataType(f.fieldType);
          return !type.isArray && ["text", "number"].includes(type.type);
        })
        .map((f) => ({
          name: f.fieldName,
          type: getUnifiedDataType(f.fieldType).type,
        })),
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you got stuck? Please read [ask] and [tour]. Afterwards, [edit] your question to add a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Main difference between map and reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934992/main-difference-between-map-and-reduce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
simpleFilter: fields
  .reduce((res, f) => {
    const type = getUnifiedDataType(f.fieldType);
    if (!type.isArray && ["text", "number"].includes(type.type)) {
      res.push({
        name: f.fieldName,
        type: getUnifiedDataType(f.fieldType).type,
      })
    }
    return res;
  }, []);
```

Comment: I feel like answering a question that does not respect [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) only encourages people to ask questions without even trying/giving enough context.